# Combine 2 different sheets with same data in Excel

Tags: excel, compare

I have the same data from different sources, both incomplete, but combined they may be less incomplete..

I have 2 files;
File #1 has; ID, Zipcode, YoB, Gender
File #2 has: Email, ID, Zipcode, Yob, Gender

The ID's in both files are the same, but #1 has some ID's that #2 hasn't, and the other way aroud.

The Email is connected to the ID. ID's are linked to the zipcode, YoB and gender. In both files are some of that info missing. 
E.g. File #1 and #2 both have ID 1234, only in #1 it only has a postal code, YoB but no Gender. And #2 has the zipcode and gender but no YoB. 

I want to have all the information in one file;
Email, ID, YoB, Zipcode, Gender

I tried to sort both ID's alphabetically and put them next to each other and search for duplicates, but because #1 has some ID's that #2 doesnt I'm not able to combine them...

What's the best way to fix this?

By the way its about 12000 ID's from #1 and 9500 from #2

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of all the unique IDs then you could create a new sheet, copy both lots of IDs into the same column and then use Advanced Filter to copy Unique records only to another column.

Then use that column to do vlookups from the two files in the columns you require.

(I'm presuming this is a one-time job and you don't mind a bit of manual-ness)...

If on your first Sheet ("Sheet1") you have:

```
ID  F_Name  S_Name  Age Favourite Cheese
1   Bob Smith   25  Brie
2   Fred    Jones   29  Cheddar
3   Jeff    Brown   18  Edam
4   Alice   Smith   39  Mozzarella
5   Mark    Jones   65  Cheddar
7   Sarah   Smith   29  Mozzarella
8   Nick    Jones   40  Brie
10  Betty   Thompson    34  Edam
```

and on your second Sheet ("Sheet2") you have:

```
ID  F_Name  S_Name  Age
1   Bob Smith   25
3   Jeff    Brown   18
4   Alice   Smith   39
5   Mark    Jones   65
6   Frank   Brown   44
7   Sarah   Smith   29
9   Tom Brown   28
10  Betty   Thompson    34
```

Then if you're combining them on a 3rd Sheet you need to do something like:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$9,COLUMN(),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$9,COLUMN(),FALSE))`

If you're trying to get to:

```
ID  F_Name  S_Name  Age Favourite Cheese
1   Bob Smith   25  Brie
2   Fred    Jones   29  Cheddar
3   Jeff    Brown   18  Edam
4   Alice   Smith   39  Mozzarella
5   Mark    Jones   65  Cheddar
6   Frank   Brown   44  0
7   Sarah   Smith   29  Mozzarella
8   Nick    Jones   40  Brie
9   Tom Brown   28  0
10  Betty   Thompson    34  Edam
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but how do I merge the data from the not unique collums?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include some similar example formulae shortly.

Comment: In the example it'll give you 0 if it's not on either list (e.g. the cheese column that's not on one of the sheets).